# How to write this SQL in a Rails way

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, join, relational-database

*rewrote the entire question so it will be clearer..

This is how my tables look like (without the useless columns)
I generated this with pgadmin

[image]

```
SELECT 
  notifications.id
FROM 
  activities, 
  notifications, 
  comments
WHERE 
  activities.trackable_id = comments.id AND
  notifications.activity_id = activities.id;
```

with pgadmin, this query gives the right result.

I don't know how to use includes (or maybe it is joins) to have 3 tables as the sql above.

my attempt of

```
@notifications = current_user.notifications.includes(:activity, :comments).where("activities.trackable_id = comments.id AND notifications.activity_id = activities.id")
```

isn't fruitful

Comment: Your example with the error is using "activities" as a schema with a table called "trackable" and a field "commentable_id". Hence the error (which doesn't say anything about a table). Don't know what you're trying to do exactly, but I think you're mixing up your rails model with your raw sql.

Comment: I am trying to get notification with a condition that relates to the 2nd order relative (trackable, as 1st is activity)

Comment: So you are trying to make two separate joins?

Comment: I don't know if separate. `activities` table have `trackable_id` which corresponds to the `id` in `comments` table. that row has `commentable_id` which I want to condition on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default when you pass ActiveRecord::Base#joins a named association, it will perform an INNER JOIN with the possible primary keys. As we can see in your model, the ids are not quite the default way, so you can distinguish which key you will be using to join the tables inside the `joins` method. Kinda something like this:

```
@notifications = current_user.notifications.
  joins("INNER JOIN activities ON notifications.activity_id = activities.id").
  joins("INNER JOIN comments ON activities.trackable_id = comments.id")
```

Comment: Thanks! so basically, I use the inner join as a condition for joining the tables?